# CPLEX programming counter skipping values

Tags: cplex

Hello I'm a beginner with regards to CPLEX and i am trying to build an optimization model to maximize profit. The whole idea is that there is the origin where the commodity originates (local production + import), a intermediate hub where the commodity is stored and the destination (consumption + export). Here is the code i am using, the inputs are pretty large.

Here is the link to the code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lUw6E8WAPVnwMOJyfW_Dv4-I_331JfaMIPfr0tbD8-M/edit?usp=sharing

So this code executes but the results generated are only partial. There is only a value generated for select ouputs and i am unsure why it does that. I know the result generated because there is no mass balance after the result is generated. Can anyone tell me what goes wrong when i execute the program?

Comment: Your model looks unbounded. Can you try to remove the objective ? regards

Comment: @AlexFleischer But thats the part i want to maximize since i want to maximize the profit within the system.  Should i just leave the maximize part in there and remove the equation?

Answer (score 0):

Can you send this mathematics model? the Constraints seem not right.